# Using STDIN & STDOUT using shell_exec or exec anything else for running a python file from command line wih input passing

Tags: php

I want to run a python file from my php code using `exec` function. To do so I use command `"python test.py"` and if I print "Hello World", it is showing.

For this my php code is like this:

```
<?php
$Data = exec("python test.py");
echo $Data;
?>
```

And the python code is:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Now I want to pass an input value say my name "Razin" to the file. So that it will print `"Hello Razin"`.

Here is my python code

```
x = input()
print ("Hello "+x)
```

which should print `Hello Razin`. And from php I catch it.

I don't want to pass arguments and use `python system` to catch that. I want to make it like code judge system.

I hear about pipe and I read it. But it didn't clear my concept.

N.B: If you can also describe if there is more than 1 input then it'll be a great help.

Comment: In order to do this, you need to modify the php file too. The user need to provide the input name, and since the user has no direct access to the python script (because it is called by the php script), the php script must handle the input. Is this fine for you? If not, I think there is no way to do it.

Comment: Look at the `proc_open()` command. It allows you to provide pipes for both input and output.

Comment: I improved the format using the multiline formatting. As I said in my comment above, consider to add more php code to show how do you collect the input name which will be passed to the python script.

Comment: Valentino, sorry for late reply. I already did it. And it is working fine. If you need help about this matter, I can help you.

Comment: Barmer, Thanks. I used `proc_open()` as you suggested. Thanks a lot/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The best way to do so is using `proc_open()`

The code sample is given below.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
                    0 => array("pipe", "r"), //input pipe
                    1 => array("pipe", "w"), //output pipe
                    2 => array("pipe", "w"), //error pipe
                );
 //calling script with max execution time 15 second
$process = proc_open("timeout 15 python3 $FileName", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
   fwrite($pipes[0], "2"); //sending 2 as input value, for multiple inputs use "2\n3" for input 2 & 3 respectively
   fclose($pipes[0]);
   $stderr_ouput = [];
   if (!feof($pipes[2])) {
   // We're acting like passthru would and displaying errors as they come in.
         $error_line = fgets($pipes[2]);
         $stderr_ouput[] = $error_line;
    }

    if (!feof($pipes[1])) {
             $print = fgets($pipes[1]); //getting output of the script
    }
}

proc_close($process);
```

Comment: NOTE: `if (!feof($pipes[1]))` will only populate `$print` with the first line of output. Instead, use `while (!feof($pipes[1]))`.